# Tunnelblick Mac Scripts

Tags: macos, openvpn, shell-script, tunnelblick

I'd like to run a script on my Mac whenever OpenVPN connects. I've checked the config on my Mac and I don't see a place for scripts anywhere. I'm running the most recent Tunnelblick (3.7.0).

**Where can I set scripts on Tunnelblick for Mac?**

Answer (score 6):

This answer is a little late, but there are actually hooks within Tunnelblick that you can use simply by putting properly named scripts in certain directories.

The [documentation for this](https://tunnelblick.net/cUsingScripts.html) is not all that much fun to read (or put into practice), so here's a summary*:

1. Create `pre-connect.sh`, `post-tun-tap-load.sh`, `connected.sh`, `reconnecting.sh` and/or `post-disconnect.sh` as is your need.
2. As root, put these files in `/Library/Application Support/Tunnelblick/Shared/<gateway>.tblk/Contents/Resources`, where `<gateway>.tblk` is a directory named after an OpenVPN configuration you've imported into Tunnelblick previously.
3. Change ownership and ACLs:

   > `bash$ sudo chown root:wheel reconnecting.sh
   >    bash$ sudo chmod 700 reconnecting.sh`

*Note that the directories I refer to might be different on your setup--I'm running macOS 10.12.6, and these steps assume you've already imported OpenVPN configurations into Tunnelblick.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me too with adjustments. Tunnelblick 3.8.1 build 5400, macOS Mojave 10.14.6.
I post my complete setup in other answer.

Comment: As a heads up, depending on your setup, your configuration files may also reside in `~/Library/Application Support/Tunnelblick/Configurations/`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [other (great) answer](https://superuser.com/a/1305361/922441) to this question, i wrote this based on `Tunnelblick 3.8.1 build 5400` and `macOS Mojave 10.14.6` with a simple example.

1. Open terminal.
2. ```
   sudo -s
   ```
3. ```
   cd /Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/Tunnelblick/Configurations/<profile>.tblk/Contents/Resources
   ```

   where `<user>` is your username on mac and `<profile>` is a VPN profile configuration you've imported into Tunnelblick

   **Complete path is something like**

   ```
   /Users/andrea/Library/Application Support/Tunnelblick/Configurations/vpncorporate.tblk/Contents/Resources
   ```

4. **connected.sh**

   ```
   nano connected.sh
   ```

   Paste following lines e.g. if you want to add routing rule when connected

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   route add -host 172.16.10.7/32 -gateway 192.168.0.244
   ```

   Reference: [route man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/4/route/)

5. **post-disconnect.sh**

   ```
   nano post-disconnect.sh
   ```

   Paste following lines e.g. if you want to delete previous added rule

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   route delete -host 172.16.10.7/32 -gateway 192.168.0.244
   ```

   Reference: [route man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/4/route/)

6. Set the right permission

   ```
   chmod 700 connected.sh
   chmod 700 post-disconnect.sh
   ```

   In my case

   ```
   -rwx------  1 root            admin    63 23 Ott 11:47 connected.sh
   -rwx------  1 root            admin    66 23 Ott 13:43 post-disconnect.sh
   ```

**A more useful and complex example about connected.sh and post-disconnect.sh may be the follow**

The idea is to get default gateway and route through that for specific IP.

4. **connected.sh**

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   DEFAULTGATEWAY="$(netstat -nar | sed -n -e '/^default/p' | head -1 | awk '{print $2}')"

   route add -host 172.16.10.7/32 -gateway $DEFAULTGATEWAY
   ```
5. **post-disconnect.sh**

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   route delete -host 172.16.10.7/32
   ```