# Is there a way to save username prefilled in TunnelBlick vpn

Tags: openvpn, tunnelblick

TunnelBlick is used to connect to vpn session. Is there a way to save username in TunnelBlick when connecting to a vpn session?

If TunnelBlick does not have this feature out-of-the-box then may be I can do it using some scripts([Tunnelblick Mac Scripts](https://superuser.com/questions/1201961/tunnelblick-mac-scripts)) that someone can help me with, to achieve this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MAC OS(most probably you are because TunnelBlick is not available in Windows OS), then you can save the details in the keychain using the checkbox `Save in Keychain`. There are "separate" checkboxes to save only the username or the password so you can just tick the checkbox related to username if you want

[image: Tunnel Blick save username in MAC OS]